# Button_data_invalid

Tags: aiogram

Всем здравствуйте. Есть функция в inline.py

```
def generate_categories_list(categories, act):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()

    for category in categories:
        cat_btn = InlineKeyboardButton(text=category, callback_data=f'{act}_category_{category}')
        markup.add(cat_btn)

    return markup
```

А также есть message_handler

```
@dp.message_handler(regexp=delete_categorie_txt)
async def delete_category(message: Message):
    categories = [category[0] for category in db.get_categories()]
    print(categories)
    await message.answer('Выберите категорию для удаления', reply_markup=generate_categories_list(categories, 'delete'))
```

При нажатие на кнопку delete_categorie_txt выводит ошибку

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-12' coro=<Dispatcher._process_polling_updates() done, defined at D:\BazaBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:407> exception=ButtonDataInvalid('Button_data_invalid')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\BazaBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 415, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\BazaBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 235, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\BazaBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\BazaBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 256, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\BazaBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 117, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\BazaBot\handlers\admins\text_handlers.py", line 36, in delete_category
    await message.answer('Выберите категорию для удаления', reply_markup=generate_categories_list(categories, "delete"))
  File "D:\BazaBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\types\message.py", line 438, in answer
    return await self.bot.send_message(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\BazaBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\bot.py", line 346, in send_message
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.SEND_MESSAGE, payload)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\BazaBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\base.py", line 236, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\BazaBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 140, in make_request
    return check_result(method, response.content_type, response.status, await response.text())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\BazaBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\bot\api.py", line 115, in check_result
    exceptions.BadRequest.detect(description)
  File "D:\BazaBot\venv\Lib\site-packages\aiogram\utils\exceptions.py", line 140, in detect
    raise err(cls.text or description)
aiogram.utils.exceptions.ButtonDataInvalid: Button_data_invalid
```

Если я убираю 'delete' то список выходит и все ок
Пытался засунуть delete в "" , все равно не помогло
В чем может быть проблема?